# jQuery sum rows adding all cells

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, sum

I've searched various SO questions about adding table columns but not many on rows. Here's what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>MAX ATK</th>
            <th>MAX DEF</th>
            <th>MAX HP</th>
            <th>Overall</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="combat">8170</td>
            <td class="combat">6504</td>
            <td class="combat">6050</td>
            <td class="total-combat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="combat">8500</td>
            <td class="combat">10200</td>
            <td class="combat">7650</td>
            <td class="total-combat"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="combat">9185</td>
            <td class="combat">7515</td>
            <td class="combat">9185</td>
            <td class="total-combat"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var sum = 0;
     $('tr').find('.combat').each(function () {
         var combat = $(this).text();
         if (!isNaN(combat) && combat.length !== 0) {
             sum += parseFloat(combat);
         }
     });

     $('.total-combat').html(sum);
 });
```

You can see my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3drnx/).

**Problem:** It's finding ALL occurrences of `.combat` and adding them up instead of only finding occurrences of `.combat` within the current row. So instead of:

```
MAX ATK MAX DEF MAX HP  Overall
 8170    6504    6050   20724
 8500    10200   7650   26350
 9185    7515    9185   25885
```

I'm getting:

```
MAX ATK MAX DEF MAX HP  Overall
 8170    6504    6050   72959
 8500    10200   7650   72959
 9185    7515    9185   72959
```

I tried using `closest()` thinking that would tell it to find the parent tr and only add tds within that tr, like so:

```
     $('.combat').closest('tr').each(function () {
```

but that didn't work :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try `$('tr').each(function(){ $(this).find('.combat')... // rest of your code })` to select all instances of `.combat` within a single `tr`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use a each loop

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //iterate through each row in the table
    $('tr').each(function () {
        //the value of sum needs to be reset for each row, so it has to be set inside the row loop
        var sum = 0
        //find the combat elements in the current row and sum it 
        $(this).find('.combat').each(function () {
            var combat = $(this).text();
            if (!isNaN(combat) && combat.length !== 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(combat);
            }
        });
        //set the value of currents rows sum to the total-combat element in the current row
        $('.total-combat', this).html(sum);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9W8qh/)

A shorter way to sum: Using unary plus - [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9W8qh/4/)

Comment: Thank you very much Arun, not only for very informative and well commented answer, but for also suggesting unary operator :)

Comment: This can't handle things like say col multiply by col before adding to the final number in the row . Eg Quantity Multiplied by Price.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this;

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $('tr').each(function () {
         var sum = 0;
         $(this).find('.combat').each(function () {
             var combat = $(this).text();
             if (!isNaN(combat) && combat.length !== 0) {
                 sum += parseFloat(combat);
             }
         });
         $(this).find('.total-combat').html(sum);
     });
 });
```

HEre is working demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/wq459/**

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $('.combat').closest('tr').find('.combat').each(function () {
```