# Adding each Table row's columns

Tags: javascript, html

My question is I have html table working hours for each day in a week. After one week one want to add that row`s hours for 7 days in 8th column that is Total, That in one week a person earned money. How to do that in JAvaScript.

Comment: What have you tried so far? any working code>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery sum rows adding all cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536448/jquery-sum-rows-adding-all-cells)

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved fairly easy with use of jQuery.

Some code to lead you can be found here: [jQuery sum rows adding all cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536448/jquery-sum-rows-adding-all-cells)

EDIT:
I made a jsFiddle for you using the codepiece given in link above:

```
     $('tr').each(function () {
     var sum = 0;
     $(this).find('.hours').each(function () {
         var hours = $(this).text();
         if (!isNaN(hours) && hours.length !== 0) {
             sum += parseFloat(hours);
         }
     });
     $(this).find('.total-hours').html(sum);
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8pf72qpg/2/